# JSP Cookie Variable Detected as Boolen rather Than Cookie

Tags: java, jsp

I am Setting a Cookie in the Servlet as Below

```
  Cookie NameCookie = new Cookie("Name", "Mugil Vannan");         
  NameCookie.setMaxAge(30*60);
  response.addCookie(NameCookie);

  Cookie LocationCookie = new Cookie("Location", "India");
  LocationCookie.setMaxAge(30*60);
  response.addCookie(LocationCookie);
```

After setting the cookie I am Trying to access the Particular Cookie set Under Name

```
Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();            


  for (int i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) 
  {
        Cookie cookie = cookies[i].getName().equals("Name");

        String cookieName  = cookie.getName();
        String cookieValue = cookie.getValue();
        out.print(cookieValue);
  }
```

Now Its getting displayed as **TypeMismatch:Cannot Convert Boolean to Cookie** at

cookies[i].getName().equals("Name");

Any Idea Why this Happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is your problem `Cookie cookie = cookies[i].getName().equals("Name");`

Did you mean:

```
Cookie cookie = cookies[i];
if (cookie.getName().equals("Name")) {
    String cookieName  = cookie.getName();
    String cookieValue = cookie.getValue();
    out.print(cookieValue);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

once your declaration is done on cookie, you don't need to declare again to reach
your cookie where key is "Name" as you wrote.

```
if(cookie[i].getName().equals("Name")){
    String cookieName  = cookie.getName();
    String cookieValue = cookie.getValue();
    out.print(cookieValue);
}
```

this will show cookie value where key(name) = "Name"